# Flexbox IE10 width issues

Tags: css, flexbox

The problem is that in IE10, the width of the columns inside the row is being calculated wrong, it appears to be adding on the width of the column margins (in total 80px), but in Firefox and Chrome it calculates it perfectly and fits everything inside 1260px. The main issue is that i have prefixed everything in what i believe is the right way, but i still get the issue.

You can see it here on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/ue2zfga6/

CSS:

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 40px; }

  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both; }

  .row *[class^="col-"] {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: auto; }

    .row *[class^="col-"]:first-child {
      margin-left: 0; }
  @media (min-width: 64em) {
    .row {
      box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      -moz-flex-direction: row;
      flex-direction: row;
      -ms-flex-direction: row; } }
  @media (min-width: 78.75em) {
    .row {
      max-width: 78.75em;
      margin: 0 auto; } }


.col-one-third {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue; }
  @media (min-width: 64em) {
    .col-one-third {
      width: 33.3%;
      margin-left: 40px; } }


.col-two-thirds {
  width: 66.7%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  background: blue; }
```

How it looks on Chrome, IE11, Firefox
[image: How it looks on Chrome, IE11, Firefox]

How it looks on IE 10, emulated inside IE11's dev console/tools
[image: How it looks on IE 10, emulated inside IE11's dev console/tools]

As you can see, the margin's are being added and going beyond the width of the container

Comment: Did you *look* at the compiled CSS to see if it is generating the results you're expecting?  The Sass code here is irrelevant because it is never served to the browser.

Comment: Of course i looked, that's the point. The compiled css is prefixing everying. I'll add the compiled part too so you can see

Comment: I've added it so you can see. As explained, it works in Firefox and Chrome, it's just ie10 that's having the issue. This is being run inside an emulator however

Comment: Cannot reproduce or I didn't understand you problem correctly. Could you please attach screenshots of wrong and expected behaviors.

Comment: @phts 2 seconds i'll get a couple

Comment: @phts i've added what i mean now :)

Comment: We cannot use SASS for much. Show us the actual CSS. Also, please create a standalone example that can be more easily recreated. If you want good and fast answers then making it easier for us is a good idea.

Comment: I know this may be silly, but the dev tools don't add a horizontal scrollbar or something like that, right?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen The CSS is there... The SASS has been removed. I've given you the link to the uploaded files so you can go to the link to see the behaviour in IE10 and other browsers

Comment: @Joseph nope, just renders it beyond the width of the container

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/ue2zfga6/ - I'll add this to the question too. @Joseph this may help you understand what i'm trying to get at haha

Comment: @AndyHolmes I'm pretty sure I understand. It's just hard to pinpoint the specifics reason when I can't test all the known bugs personally. See updates to my answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I don't have IE10 available, but it seems like you should look at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) and the known issues. Or maybe this [user moderated list](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) on Github. Or maybe the comment section of the [css-tricks guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

The caniuse site mentions:

> IE10 and IE11 default values for flex are `0 0 auto` rather than `0 1 auto`, as per the draft spec, as of September 2013.

and

> In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit height property.

The Github site mentions:

> When using align-items:center on a flex container in the column direction, the contents of flex item, if too big, will overflow their container in IE 10-11.
>
> Workaround
>
> Most of the time, this can be fixed by simply setting max-width:100% on the flex item. If the flex item has a padding or border set, you'll also need to make sure to use box-sizing:border-box to account for that space. If the flex item has a margin, using box-sizing alone will not work, so you may need to use a container element with padding instead.

This [comment on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#comment-1592128) shows that where you would normally say `flex: 1;` you should say `-ms-flex: 1 0 auto;`

Also, you should change your code where it does something like this:

```
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-moz-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
```

to this:

```
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-moz-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
```

You always want the proper line of code—the one without flags— at the bottom of the prefix list.

Comment: Thanks for the info Joseph. If you take a look at the question now, i have added screenshots of how it looks in chrome, and how it looks in emulated ie10

Comment: I updated my answer, and I'm pretty sure the excerpt from the Github list of flexbox bugs is the one you're dealing with.

Comment: Well... this is embarrassing. I forgot to add `flex: 1` to the tablet/desktop view. Added it, added your `ms-flex: 1 0 auto;` as well for safety and it looks okay. Haha, thank you so much

Comment: In IE10: I was facing issue with few elements where width:100% was not working. But once I applied -ms-flex-direction: column, Than it's working. Can anyone explain to me why is this with IE10 only?

Comment: @JayeshDhandha Those flag lines are used when a CSS functionality is not completely implemented or is in "beta" and tells the web rendering engines to do the CSS rule regardless of that. Thus, in IE10, the flex-direction column functionality must not be completely implemented.